# Open Video Pop up on the same WebPage when the user clicks on play

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html, css

```
  <div class="player"><iframe src="http://player.vimeo.com/video/<?= $vimeo;?>?title=0&amp;byline=0&amp;portrait=0&amp;color=abcc16&amp;autoplay=0" width="150" height="150" frameborder="0" webkitAllowFullScreen allowFullScreen></iframe></div>
```

How do i open a popup window on the same page with the cross(x) on top when i click on play button for the video displayed on the html page? And it has to display Watch Video on the video Window before the user clicks on it. I am currently using the above code in php to display the frame window in the browser.

Comment: since you dont want the video to actually be a video, why not use a jpeg for the click target, then it will say watch video

Answer (score 1):

jquery + colorbox plugin http://www.jacklmoore.com/colorbox

Open a colorbox popup with the "watch video" message in it. Add `click` handler that replaces the message with the video iframe.

Comment: I am completly new to jquery color box, i have downloaded it and it has got some examples ? could you please tell me which of those work for me?@Tim